# parse python byte array to golang []byte

Tags: python, go

I need parse python's dict to golang's map, and I use a package called "go-python".
Now, I use python's msgpack pack the dict to a byte array, and how can't I parse it to golang's []byte.

```
func GoMap(dict *python.PyObject) map[string]interface{} {
  pymp := python.PyImport_ImportModule("msgpack")
  pack := pymp.GetAttrString("packb")
  packArgs := python.PyTuple_New(1)
  python.PyTuple_SetItem(packArgs, 0, dict)
  temp := pack.Call(packArgs, python.PyDict_New())
  tempLen := python.PyString_Size(temp)
  bstr := python.PyString_AsString(temp)
  fmt.Println("len temp", tempLen)
  fmt.Println("len bstr", len(bstr))
  bytestr := []byte(bstr)
  var out map[string]interface{}
  err := msgpack.Unmarshal(bytestr, &out)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  return out
}
```

The result:
len temp 370
len bstr 148
panic: EOF

I use Pystring_AsString parse python's byte array to go str, If the dict has a value 0, it get eof

Comment: Please post a minimal code snippet demonstrating your issue.

Comment: If you can, maybe use JSON as an intermediary format between python and Go, using the ad-hoc modules in each languages

Comment: Thanks. I had post a minimal code. And I use msgpack because of its performance.